# How to delay a program from starting on boot up - Xubuntu

Tags: startup, xubuntu

I am running Xubuntu and have several programs automatically starting when the computer powers up. All the programs starting at once is causing me issues with having the programs talk to each other. Instead, I would like to stage the starting of each program with program A starting first, then five seconds later program B starts and so on. How do I do this?

Comment: So far, I have tried 'X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay' but it is not recognized by Xubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement it like this (probably not an Xubuntu friendly way, but should work):
create a startup script which will start all required program, and make that script the only "auto-started" program with Xubuntu tools.
Script can look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
program1 &
sleep 5
program2 &
sleep 5
program3 &
```

Or like this, which will look better if you have multiple programs to launch:

```
#!/bin/sh
PROGS=(
  "program1 args"
  "program3"
  program2
  # ...
)

for prog in "${PROGS[@]}"; do
  ${prog} &  # no quotes here, because we want to support args
  sleep 5
done
```

Comment: Better quit using DMs and use `xinit`/`startx` intead,